# Automating NodeJS scripts with Google Cloud Platform

Tags: node.js, cron, google-cloud-platform

My question is in regards to clarification and/or anybodies previous experience with NodeJS and Google Cloud Platform (GCP).

I have developed numerous NodeJS scripts that read and transform serveral JSON sports feed in order to populate a Google Firebase database backend.

The NodeJS scripts work exactly as desired; with the exception that I need to run/execute the NodeJs script manually in order to populate the backend. I obviously want this to be automatically, lets say an interval of every 2 mins.

I am unclear on how to achieve this!? Does GCP offer a cron job that can execute my NodeJS on a specific time interval? If so how should I implement this?!

Comment: Which GCP service are you using to run your nodeJS scripts? For example, are are you using Google Compute Engine instances or App Engine?

Comment: So based on my understanding of the services: `App Engine` is a Platform-as-a-Service. It means that you simply deploy your code, and the platform does everything else for you. For example, if your app becomes very successful, App Engine will automatically create more instances to handle the increased volume.
`Compute Engine` is an Infrastructure-as-a-Service. You have to create and configure your own virtual machine instances. It gives you more flexibility and generally costs much less than App Engine. The drawback is that you have to manage your app and virtual machines yourself.

Comment: I'm "planning" on utilizing `compute engine` since I will only be needing to call the scripts "every 2 mins" as an example. I don't really need scaling; other than on the Firebase backend which would be getting the data written to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on using Compute Engine you can just use a cron job which comes with the both the Debian and Red Hat Linux public images available within Google Cloud Platform.

You could create an enrty like this to run the script every 2 hours.

```
* /2* * * * /usr/local/bin/node /home/example/script.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples of how to do this using cron and appengine:

- https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron
- https://mhaligowski.github.io/blog/2017/05/25/scheduled-cloud-function-execution.html

The basic idea is the same: one appengine app for cron, where you tell it what URL to get, at what frequency. What is serving at the URL is immaterial here, you would obviously have your nodejs app in an appengine instance, serving URLs that match those given to cron. The cron portion of the examples is independent of language, it is REST based.

So the steps for you would be:

1. Setup your nodejs app in GAE the standard way (regardless of the
   fact that you want your app URLs called at intervals)
2. Setup your cron app in GAE as explained in those examples
3. Notice your nodejs app of step 1 being called as you specified in step 2!

Comment: Hello Oliver, this is using python.. which is OK I guess, but I was looking for not using anything but cron job and NodeJS (possibly Express) to get this done.

Comment: @Learn2Code The technique is language independant because it is URL based. The examples happen to use Python to serve URL but that's beside the point; if you have nodejs app, just put it in appengine as you would normally, so explaining how to do this is outside the scope of this quesiton, it is not particular to cron. I have tried to clarify my answer.

Comment: would this work with GAE standard environment or on on the flex environment !?

Comment: The node portion requests a flex instance